# PHP cambiar al funcionalidad

Tags: php

Hola amigos tengo un problema es que tengo un codigo que funciona bajo una funcionalidad de php 8.0 y necesito subir esta funcionalidad a php 7.2 y no puedo actualziar el servidor, hay alguna manera de modificar la funcion por otra para que haga lo mismo esta funcion se llamara str_contains.

```
 if (!str_contains($info['programa_uvi'], 'EMPRESAS') || str_contains($info['programa_uvi'], 'TECNICO PROFESIONAL')) {
                           if (str_contains($info['programa_uvi'], 'TECNICO')) {
                              echo "Por lo tanto, una vez realizado el an&aacutelisis de homologaci&oacuten, y de ser aceptado el presente, deber&aacute cursar y aprobar " . $tecnico . " espacios acad&eacutemicos equivalentes " . $cre_tecnico . " cr&eacuteditos del plan de estudios de la Uvirtual, para as&iacute nivelar y finalmente optar por el t&iacutetulo " . $info['programa_uvi'] . ". Dichos espacios acad&eacutemicos si se toma en cada periodo 9 creditos se podrian demorar aproximadamente ";
                              if (round(($cre_tecnico / 9), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) < 0.5) {
                                 echo "1 periodo trimestral.";
                              } else {
                                 echo round(($cre_tecnico / 9), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . " periodos trimestrales.<br><br>";
                              }
                                  echo "Espacios academicos pendientes por cursar y aprobar de acuerdo al nivel de formacion para obtener el titulo: Tecnico ".$tecnico.", Tecnologico ".$tecnologo-$tecnico.", Universitario ".$profesional-$tecnologo.".";
                           }
```

Comment: str_contains fue introducida en PHP8, debes cambiarla por strpos y chequear que no devuelva false

Comment: Hay algun ejemplo de como referencia en este caso, digamos comparandola con TECNICO

Comment: si en google hay varias y en el manual de php tambien: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si no [existe la función](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.function-exists.php), puedes crearla tratando de simular el comportamiento de [la original](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php):

```
if(!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains($pajar = '', $aguja = '') {
        if($aguja === '') {
            // En caso de cadena vacía, siempre se devuelve verdadero
            return true;
        }
        return (mb_strpos($pajar, $aguja) !== false);
    }
}
```

**Notas:**

- Crear la función solo si no existe, te evitará problemas si llegas a actualizar la versión de PHP.
- str_contains() es una función "binary-safe" y sería muy complicado lograr ese comportamiento, pero mientras la uses solo con cadenas no tendrás problemas.
- Dentro de la función "propia" se usa [mb_strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strpos.php) para soportar juegos de caracteres multibyte, como UTF8.
- mb_strpos() devuelve falso en caso de no encontrar la cadena o un entero con la posición en que se encontró, entonces la función "propia" analiza:

  - "Si el valor no es falso"

    - La cadena buscada existe en el texto: Devuelve verdadero
  - "De lo contrario"

    - No se encontró la cadena: Devuelve falso

Comment: No habia caido en cuenta de esa posibilidad en crear la funcion como tal, me sirvio a la perfección. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

cambia **str_contains** por **strpos** para lograr ´backward compatibility´:

```
if (strpos($info['programa_uvi'], 'EMPRESAS') !== false || strpos($info['programa_uvi'], 'TECNICO PROFESIONAL') !== false) {
                           if (strpos($info['programa_uvi'], 'TECNICO') !== false) {
                              echo "Por lo tanto, una vez realizado el an&aacutelisis de homologaci&oacuten, y de ser aceptado el presente, deber&aacute cursar y aprobar " . $tecnico . " espacios acad&eacutemicos equivalentes " . $cre_tecnico . " cr&eacuteditos del plan de estudios de la Uvirtual, para as&iacute nivelar y finalmente optar por el t&iacutetulo " . $info['programa_uvi'] . ". Dichos espacios acad&eacutemicos si se toma en cada periodo 9 creditos se podrian demorar aproximadamente ";
                              if (round(($cre_tecnico / 9), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) < 0.5) {
                                 echo "1 periodo trimestral.";
                              } else {
                                 echo round(($cre_tecnico / 9), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . " periodos trimestrales.<br><br>";
                              }
                                  echo "Espacios academicos pendientes por cursar y aprobar de acuerdo al nivel de formacion para obtener el titulo: Tecnico ".$tecnico.", Tecnologico ".$tecnologo-$tecnico.", Universitario ".$profesional-$tecnologo.".";
                           }
```

`strpos` devuelva la posición de la primera ocurrencia del texto buscado dentro de la cadena, en caso de no aparecer retorna `false`.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Gracias